# Get the same rows from two data frames without merge or dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, merge, subset

I have to get the same rows from two datasets without using function as merge or packages like dplyr. basically I can only use for cycles and if.

I've come up to this solution:

#since the two data frames are really big, I've reduced them using:

```
tab1 <- tab1[seq(800,1000),]
tab2 <- tab2[seq(800,1000),]

rname1 <- rownames(tab1)
rname2 <- rownames(tab2)
vecres <- c()
```

#since I need the results from only the first 3 columns of datasets:

```
for (i in rname1) { 
  a <- tab1[i,c(1,2,3)]
  for (j in rname2) {
    b <- tab2[j,c(1,2,3)] 
   
    cond <- a == b
    singlecond <- all(cond)
   
    if (singlecond) {vecres[i] <- c(a[i,c(1,2,3)])} 
      
    
  }
  
}
```

I. don't know how to go on and where I'm making mistakes... please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
tab1[do.call(paste, tab1[1:3]) %in% do.call(paste, tab2[1:3]), ]
```

If you really want `for` loops, you can try

```
vecres <- c()
for (i in rname1) {
    a <- tab1[i, c(1, 2, 3)]
    for (j in rname2) {
        b <- tab2[j, c(1, 2, 3)]

        cond <- a == b
        singlecond <- all(cond)

        if (singlecond) {
            vecres <- c(vecres, i)
        }
    }
}
tab1[vecres,]
```

Comment: Thanks, it surely works, but I must do it using for cycles and if conditions :)

Comment: @UmbertoGreco See my updates

Comment: THANKS!!!! It was so obvious that I couldn't see it!!!! :D